# Ingesting data in MongoDB with mongodb-output-plugin in Logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to ingest data from a txt file in MongoDB (Machine 1), using Logstash (Machine 2).
I set a DB and a collection with Compass and I am using the mongodb-output-plugin in Logstash.
Here's the Logstash conf file:

```
input
{
        file {
                path => "/home/user/Data"
                type => "cisco-asa"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

filter
{
        grok {
        match => { "message" => "^%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:device_src} %%{CISCO_REASON:facility}-%{INT:severity_level}-%{CISCO_REASON:facility_mnemonic}: %{GREEDY>
        }


        date {
                match => ["syslog_timestamp", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
                target => "@timestamp"
        }

}

output
{
        stdout {
                codec => dots
        }

        mongodb {
          id => "mongo-cisco"
          collection => "Cisco ASA"
          database => "Logs"
          uri => "mongodb+srv://user:pass@192.168.10.9:27017/Logs"
        }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the Logstash output:

[Logstash output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP4G1.png)

```
[2021-03-27T13:29:35,178][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
.............................................................................................................................
[2021-03-27T13:30:06,201][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main][mongo-cisco] Failed to send event to MongoDB, retrying in 3 seconds {:event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x6d0984a>, :exception=>#<Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x6711494c @tag_sets=[], @server_selection_timeout=30, @options={:database=>"Logs", :user=>"username", :password=>"passwd"}>>}
```

PS: this is my first time using MongoDB

Comment: Hi, please add error that you are getting. The question is not clear.

Comment: There you go. I edited the post.